# When and why attached vector is ambiguously defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

So I've been trying to calculate Jordan basis   for this matrix
   \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 3 & 1 & 5 \\\
    0 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 3  \\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & -3 \\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 6 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -6 & 7\end{pmatrix}
and i found out eigenvectors \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 9 & -1 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} and attached ones being \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 9/16 & 7/6 & -1/3 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -3/8 & -1/8 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
But im being told that the last one is being ambiguously defined. How could this be?

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: I'm sorry if my english is preventing me from explaining this right, it's hard to find a translation for specific terms. The last vector of the Jordan basis {0,-3/8,-1/8,0,0} is 
ambiguously defined (I'm not sure if this is the correct term, what I mean is that it has different forms)  and I'm trying to find it's other forms and why they exist in the first place

Comment: Do you mean something besides scalar multiples of that vector?

Comment: Yes, something like that. 
i guess it has something to do with (A-E)h2={0,-1,0,0,0}

Comment: By the way, your first eigenvector isn’t actually an eigenvector of the matrix and you should have found two linearly-independent eigenvectors of $1$.

Comment: Yes, i wrote the matrix wrong

Comment: You’ve also mistyped one of the generalized eigenvectors.